# Who can see how many people have uninstalled an app?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, uninstallation

A few months ago I installed a free comic viewer app from a local publisher because I always have bought the comics on paper anyway so it seemed a logical way to do.

This publisher is boasting about the thousands of downloads he got for his app.

However, having seen the app, I uninstalled it the day after because it simply was not good enough (and took to much memory).

So I am just wondering: we always see how many downloads an app has. But can we see somewhere how many uninstalls have occurred?

Comment: I think only the app's publisher can see this, but I'm not positive.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to see this fro the user's end.   Generally read through the comments.  People are very vocal about their opinion.  And if it has truly been uninstalled that many times, beleive me, people will say why and you will get a good indication.

And yes, a developer does get daily statistics on installs/uninstalls.